# Reference data of d3 element to parent node data

Tags: inheritance, d3.js, data-binding

I am making a pie chart with d3. Each piece of the graph, has an inner path and and outer path. That way, when the both set of paths need to transform, they are based on the same data set.

So my thought was to bind the data to a set of 'g' (with class '.piece') and then let both the path sets ('.innerpath' and '.outerpath') have there data point to their parent data set.

How can I do this?

```
pieces = container.selectAll('.piece')
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append('g')
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles

outerPaths = pieces.append('path')
    .data(function(){
    // ??
    }).attr('d', outerArc)
    .attr('class', 'outerpath');
```

Comment: well in that case you don't need to have the data block, for appending paths.
This should work `outerPaths = pieces.append('path')
.attr('d', outerArc)
.attr('class', 'outerpath');`

Comment: I think the problem is that on the arctween of the paths, I am using this._current (see https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) which isn't there for the paths.

Comment: yes i presume you may have missed this line `.each(function(d) { this._current = d; }); // store the initial angles` where start angle is attached to the path(In your case it should be the group).

Comment: I have that line on my .pieces. Are you saying I should have it as well on my paths? Can I point that value to pieces. Something like `.each(function(d) { this._current = this.parentNode._current; });` (that gives some unexpected results)

Comment: I have put it up on a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/TnSaF4kgdAfWTERxm2nt?p=preview
This has two paths in a group.
Please have a look. Hope this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the path add group.

```
  var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie)
    .enter().append("g");
```

To the group add path with outer arc.

```
path.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
  .classed("outer", true)//add class outer
  .attr("d", arco)
  .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
```

To the group add path with inner arc.

```
path.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i + 1); })
  .classed("inner", true)//add class inner
  .attr("d", arci)
  .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
```

On change tween both paths.

```
function change() {
    var value = this.value;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    pie.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); // change the value function
    path = path.data(pie); // compute the new angles
    path.select(".outer").transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweeno); // redraw the arcs
    path.select(".inner").transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweeni); // redraw the arcs
  }
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnSaF4kgdAfWTERxm2nt?p=preview)